# How to Compile Calindori via Git? Unknown cmake command

Tags: software-installation, kde, compiling, git

I'd like to use Calindori, it is not in Synaptic repo, nor can I find a Snapd or Flathub for Calindori.

Link to the compile directions I attempted to follow:
https://invent.kde.org/plasma-mobile/calindori#compile

```
git clone https://invent.kde.org/kde/calindori.git
cd calindori
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j$(nproc)
```

Here is what happens in my terminal (I have no clue what to enter to make 'cmake' work properly):

```
s@s-virtualbox:~$ git clone https://invent.kde.org/kde/calindori.git
Cloning into 'calindori'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4147, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (848/848), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Total 4147 (delta 595), reused 786 (delta 538), pack-reused 3299
Receiving objects: 100% (4147/4147), 1.69 MiB | 2.06 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3067/3067), done.
s@s-virtualbox:~$ cd calindori
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori$ mkdir build
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori$ cd build
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ECM" (requested
  version 5.62.0) with any of the following names:

    ECMConfig.cmake
    ecm-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ECM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ECM_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ECM" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/s/calindori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori/build$ make -j$(nproc)
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori/build$
```

These steps created a folder for calindori in my 'home' folder with some files included in it, but nothing is executable in its current state. I don't know what to enter after 'cmake' the ".." given by the Git Readme instructions obviously does nothing useful.

/////////////////////////\\\\\

[UPDATE, following day!]

I am re-trying this on a Debian-based Sparky Linux 7 in KDE Plasma as I had already completely hosed my Ubuntu installation last night by the time the updated responses came in.

After installing those numerous packages, I am still missing something when it comes time to 'cmake'.

This is the cmake step in Konsole:

```
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Installing in /usr/local. Run /home/s/Downloads/calindori/build/prefix.sh to set the environment for calindori.
-- Could not set up the appstream test. appstreamcli is missing.
fatal: HEAD does not point to a branch
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMFindModuleHelpers.cmake:112 (message):
  Your project should require at least CMake 3.16.0 to use FindKF5.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:30 (ecm_find_package_version_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found KF5Config: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Config/KF5ConfigConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5Kirigami2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Kirigami2/KF5Kirigami2Config.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5I18n (missing: KF5I18n_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5I18n: found neither KF5I18nConfig.cmake nor kf5i18n-config.cmake 
-- Found KF5CoreAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CoreAddons/KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5CalendarCore: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CalendarCore/KF5CalendarCoreConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5Notifications (missing: KF5Notifications_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Notifications: found neither KF5NotificationsConfig.cmake nor kf5notifications-config.cmake 
-- Found KF5People: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5People/KF5PeopleConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find KF5 (missing: I18n Notifications) (found suitable version
  "5.88.0", minimum required is "5.62.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:93 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/s/Downloads/calindori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Back to cmake:

```
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Installing in /usr/local. Run /home/s/Downloads/calindori/build/prefix.sh to set the environment for calindori.
-- Could not set up the appstream test. appstreamcli is missing.
fatal: HEAD does not point to a branch
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMFindModuleHelpers.cmake:112 (message):
  Your project should require at least CMake 3.16.0 to use FindKF5.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:30 (ecm_find_package_version_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found KF5Config: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Config/KF5ConfigConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5Kirigami2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Kirigami2/KF5Kirigami2Config.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5I18n (missing: KF5I18n_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5I18n: found neither KF5I18nConfig.cmake nor kf5i18n-config.cmake 
-- Found KF5CoreAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CoreAddons/KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5CalendarCore: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CalendarCore/KF5CalendarCoreConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5Notifications (missing: KF5Notifications_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Notifications: found neither KF5NotificationsConfig.cmake nor kf5notifications-config.cmake 
-- Found KF5People: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5People/KF5PeopleConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find KF5 (missing: I18n Notifications) (found suitable version
  "5.88.0", minimum required is "5.62.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:93 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/s/Downloads/calindori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

////////////\\\\

[UPDATE: possible success?]

I had to download a few additional packages to get this far, namely:
`kf5-messagelib-data`
(Also ANY package in the Synaptic repository that started with:)
"libkf5noti" was also downloaded.

At least 60 packages (give or take 20, including dependencies) total..

TERMINAL SESSION:

```
s@s-virtualbox:~$ qdbus org.kde.kded5 /kded unloadModule kscreen
true
s@s-virtualbox:~$ cd ~/Downloads
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads$ git clone https://invent.kde.org/kde/calindori.git -b v21.08
Cloning into 'calindori'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4147, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (848/848), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Total 4147 (delta 595), reused 786 (delta 538), pack-reused 3299
Receiving objects: 100% (4147/4147), 1.69 MiB | 2.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3067/3067), done.
Note: switching to 'f739058093ab148d2e66ffe4ff7f028edf2dde86'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads$ cd calindori
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori$ mkdir build
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori$ cd build
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Installing in /usr/local. Run /home/s/Downloads/calindori/build/prefix.sh to set the environment for calindori.
-- Could not set up the appstream test. appstreamcli is missing.
fatal: HEAD does not point to a branch
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMFindModuleHelpers.cmake:112 (message):
  Your project should require at least CMake 3.16.0 to use FindKF5.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:30 (ecm_find_package_version_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found KF5Config: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Config/KF5ConfigConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5Kirigami2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Kirigami2/KF5Kirigami2Config.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found Gettext: /usr/bin/msgmerge (found version "0.21") 
-- Found KF5I18n: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5I18n/KF5I18nConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5CoreAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CoreAddons/KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5CalendarCore: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CalendarCore/KF5CalendarCoreConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5Notifications: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Notifications/KF5NotificationsConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5People: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5People/KF5PeopleConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5: success (found suitable version "5.88.0", minimum required is "5.62.0") found components: Config Kirigami2 I18n CoreAddons CalendarCore Notifications People 
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMFindModuleHelpers.cmake:112 (message):
  Your project should require at least CMake 3.16.0 to use FindKF5.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:30 (ecm_find_package_version_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found KF5DBusAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5DBusAddons/KF5DBusAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.88.0") 
-- Found KF5: success (found suitable version "5.88.0", minimum required is "5.62.0") found components: DBusAddons 
-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * ECM (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * Qt5Qml
 * Qt5QmlModels (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * Qt5Quick
 * Qt5QuickControls2
 * Qt5Svg
 * Qt5Network
 * Qt5Test
 * KF5Config (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * KF5Kirigami2 (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * Gettext
 * KF5I18n (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * KF5CoreAddons (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * KF5CalendarCore (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * Qt5Gui (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * KF5Notifications (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * Qt5Core (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * Qt5Widgets (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * KF5People (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * Qt5 (required version >= 5.14.0)
 * Qt5DBus (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * KF5DBusAddons (required version >= 5.62.0)
 * KF5 (required version >= 5.62.0)

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/s/Downloads/calindori/build
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ make -j$(nproc)
[  3%] Automatic MOC for target calindori
[  3%] Built target calindori_autogen
[  6%] Automatic RCC for resources.qrc
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/calindori_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/calindoriconfig.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/localcalendar.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/incidencealarmsmodel.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/daysofmonthmodel.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/recurrenceperiodmodel.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/daysofmonthincidencemodel.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/incidencemodel.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/alarmchecker.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/datahandler.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/calendarcontroller.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/attendeesmodel.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/calindori.dir/calindori_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_resources.cpp.o
[ 51%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/calindori
[ 51%] Built target calindori
[ 54%] Automatic MOC for target calindac
[ 54%] Built target calindac_autogen
[ 57%] Generating powermanagementadaptor.cpp, powermanagementadaptor.h
[ 60%] Generating powermanagementadaptor.moc
[ 63%] Generating calindacadaptor.cpp, calindacadaptor.h
[ 66%] Generating calindacadaptor.moc
[ 69%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/calindac_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/calalarmclient.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/calindacmain.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/alarmsmodel.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/alarmnotification.cpp.o
[ 84%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/notificationhandler.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/solidwakeupbackend.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/wakeupmanager.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/calindacadaptor.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object calindac/CMakeFiles/calindac.dir/powermanagementadaptor.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/calindac
[100%] Built target calindac
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for s: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for s: 
[  3%] Automatic MOC for target calindori
[  3%] Built target calindori_autogen
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target calindori
[ 51%] Built target calindori
[ 54%] Automatic MOC for target calindac
[ 54%] Built target calindac_autogen
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target calindac
[100%] Built target calindac
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/metainfo/org.kde.calindori.appdata.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/applications/org.kde.calindori.desktop
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/calindori
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/calindori" to "/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/calindori.svg
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/calindac
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/calindac" to "/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
-- Installing: /usr/local/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.calindac.desktop
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/knotifications5/calindac.notifyrc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.calindac.service
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ 
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ qdbus org.kde.kded5 /kde unloadModule -kscreen
Cannot find '.unloadModule' in object /kde at org.kde.kded5
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ qdbus org.kde.kded5 /kded unloadModule -kscreen
false
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$ qdbus org.kde.kded5 /kded unloadModule kscreen
true
s@s-virtualbox:~/Downloads/calindori/build$
```

Next I will try executing 'calindori'.

Comment: This application seems like a program for KDE Mobile. Are you SURE you want to build this piece of software?

Comment: The `..` does something useful - it tells `cmake` to look for the CMakeLists.txt file in the parent directory, rather than in the out-of-tree `build` directory where it's being run.

Comment: ... fwiw a `ECMConfig.cmake` file appears to be provided by package [extra-cmake-modules](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/extra-cmake-modules/filelist)

Comment: It is a good program. Currently, Manjaro has it in their native repository and it works for both KDE Plasma desktop as well as XFCE desktop. There is no reason for Calindori to be confined to Pinephone ARM usage. It already works well in 64 bit, in Arch. Why not see if it can work in Ubuntu and Debian based distrobutions?  BTW I'm new to Linux so excuse me if I am asking for the impossible.

Comment: Response @steeldriver. I was following the instructions included in the Readme and did not deviate. ".." didn't work for my attempt using 'cmake'. I am new to Linux. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @NewtoLinux please install the `extra-cmake-modules` package on your system, then try the suggested `cmake` command again.

Comment: I downloaded several (at least 5-6) packages that came up in Synaptic search results using the search term: "cmake-module". Then I retried the entire process again recieving error messages. I will post current results then try to find that specific "extra-cmake-modules" package in Synaptic.  TERMINAL:  s@s-virtualbox:~$ git clone https://invent.kde.org/kde/calindori.git
Cloning into 'calindori'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4147, done.

Comment: remote: Counting objects: 100% (848/848), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Total 4147 (delta 595), reused 786 (delta 538), pack-reused 3299
Receiving objects: 100% (4147/4147), 1.69 MiB | 2.06 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3067/3067), done.
s@s-virtualbox:~$ cd calindori
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori$ mkdir build
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori$ cd build
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0

Comment: -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

Comment: -- No qmake Qt5 binary found. Can't check QT_INSTALL_PREFIX
Installing in /usr. Run /home/s/calindori/build/prefix.sh to set the environm
ent for calindori.
-- Setting build type to 'Debug' as none was specified.
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME

Comment: -- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME - Success
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (find_package):
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested    
 version 5.14.0) with any of the following names:                            
                                                                             
   Qt5Config.cmake                                                           
   qt5-config.cmake

Comment: Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"  
 to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a      
 separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.         
                                                                             
                                                                             
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/s/calindori/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
s@s-virtualbox:~/calindori/build$

Comment: I double checked Synaptic by searching for "extra-cmake-modules" ALL 3 results that came up I already have on my system prior to making the last attempt I just posted above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting additional information in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install build-dependencies by consulting with [ArchLinux AUR PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=calindori-git) and manual retries first by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git build-essential qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake \
qtbase5-dev-tools cmake extra-cmake-modules libqt5svg5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev \
qtquickcontrols2-5-dev libkf5config-dev kirigami2-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev \
libkf5calendarcore-dev libkf5notifications-dev libkf5people-dev libkf5dbusaddons-dev \
qml-module-org-kde-people breeze adwaita-icon-theme-full libadwaitaqt-dev \
gnome-themes-extra qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 breeze-gtk-theme
```

Then clone repository with the corresponding `v21.08` [tag](https://invent.kde.org/plasma-mobile/calindori/-/tags)/version which normally suits yours Ubuntu 21.10:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://invent.kde.org/kde/calindori.git -b v21.08
cd calindori
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo

make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Finally run Calindori by `calindori` and enjoy.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I only had to download some extra packages to get the file "KF5Notifications" which was missing. The program 'calindori' so far seems to execute just fine. I'm sure this would work on Ubuntu, as I am using Debian based Sparky7 Kde at the moment. I hosed my Ubuntu yesterday by downloading and deleting too many packages.

Comment: I wrote this answer and tested it in Ubuntu 21.10. Other non-Ubuntu systems are off-topic  here, but will work (as you see). So you can accept this answer by using grey checkmark at the left of answer to mark problem solved.

Comment: It should be checked. I hope this Q&A sticks around for awhile as I will need this info again in the near future while setting up Calindori on bare metal.